# Integration of jenkins with xray jira

Tags: jenkins, jira, aws-xray

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with X ray and Jira on cloud. I have installed X ray Jira plugins on Jenkins and trying to configure but getting error as below.

Comment: Error not found.

Comment: Which error? What did you try to configure? Maybe it is better to add relevant secreenshots.  Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't believe its the ["aws-xray"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-xray.html) that you mean. Its probably this [xray](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xray-connector/), right?